# No exception is thrown if LDAP server is disconnected while fetching records

Tags: java, exception, ldap

I am working on something which needs to interact with LDAP server and fetch some user records in set of 1000. There is one strange behavior that we are observing,

let's say if there this read operation executing, and somehow the LDAP server gets turned-off/killed, in this scenario strangely no Exception is thrown.

I was expecting that a `NamingExcption` would be thrown.

Code that i am using to read from server:

```
NamingEnumeration searchResults = ldapContext.search(userBaseDN, searchFilterForUsers, searchCtrls);

while (searchResults != null && searchResults.hasMoreElements())
{
  SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) searchResults.next();
  // do something with searchResult 
}
```

I am searching Google for any hints, it would be nice if you can put me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to set a read timeout. NB `searchResuots` cannot be null.

Comment: I have found that `hasMoreElements()` method won't ever throw any exception instead use `hasMore()` method.

Answer (score 1):

As @EJP said, you should to set the "[com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/readtimeout.html)".
Why someone thought that NOT setting some default on this was a good idea I will never know.

I also use a connection test isAlive() method where I query for a non-existent control. Something like (supportedControl=0.0.0.0.0.0.0).

Comment: Thanks. I found that using hasMore() instead of hasMoreElements() solved the issue and i agree setting a timeout.